# Как остановить потоки при получения данных отличных от None хотя бы из 1 потока?

Tags: python, asyncio

Есть кусок функции.
Сейчас в `data_list` попадают в пересмешку и данные и `None`.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при попадании первых данных (не `None`) в `data_list` мы не дожидались выполнения остальных потоков.

```
def check_site(self, log):
    site = ['https://yandex.ru/internet', 'https://wtfismyip.com', 'https://whoer.net', 'https://2ip.ru']
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        futures = [loop.run_in_executor(pool, check_site, self.user, self.password, self.ip, self.port,
                                        self.protocol, url, log) for url in site]
        data_list = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```

Необходимо также отметить, что запросы отправляются через curl в формате:

```
curl -x http://usbW1q:fE3U35@193.111.5.203:8000 https://8.8.8.8 -w %{time_connect}
```

Может я что то не так делаю(((

Вот функция где я делаю `futures` и вызывают функцию `wait_first_completed_not_none`

```
async def check_dns(self, log):
    dns = ['https://google.com', 'https://208.67.222.222']
    protocols = ['http', 'socks5']
    futures = [asyncio.create_task(check_dns_no_class(self.user, self.password, self.ip, self.port, url, protocol,
                                                      log)) for url in dns for protocol in protocols]
    data = await wait_first_completed_not_none(futures)
```

и в `data` попадают данные которые были первыми получены только при выполнении всех `futures` и все `futures`  выполняются по очереди

а тут я вызываю функцию `proxy.check_dns`

```
def run(proxy_attr, log, connection):
    proxy = Proxy(proxy_attr[0], proxy_attr[1], proxy_attr[2], proxy_attr[3])
    log.info(f'Check proxy: {proxy.ip}:{proxy.port}:{proxy.user}:{proxy.password}')
    id_proxy = add_proxy_to_database(connection, proxy)
    log.info(f'Proxy: {proxy.ip}:{proxy.port}:{proxy.user}:{proxy.password} add database')
    asyncio.run(proxy.check_dns(log))
```

Comment: В принципе, чтобы остановиться при получении первых данных можно использовать [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) с параметром `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`. Если нужно проверять чтобы результат был не None, можно проверять результат в done, и повторять `asynco.wait(pending)`, пока не вернется что-то кроме None.

Comment: return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED - если это использовать и первым значением вернется None то все остановится?

Comment: Нет, остальные задачи продолжат работу.

Comment: не могу понять как интегрировать это в мой код((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы остановиться при завершении первого же таска, можно использовать [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) с параметром `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`. Если нужно проверять чтобы результат был не `None`, можно проверять результат в `done`, и повторять `asynco.wait(pending)`, пока не вернется что-то кроме `None`.

Пример реализации ожидания первого таска, вернувшего не `None`, для асинхронных http запросов использую [aiohttp](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import traceback


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        try:
            return await response.text()
        except Exception:
            # Просто печатаем ошибку и возвращаем None
            traceback.print_exc()  
            return None


async def wait_first_completed_not_none(futures):
    while True:
        # Если получили пустой список,
        # сразу возвращаем None, иначе будет бесконечный цикл
        if not futures:
            return None

        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(futures, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        # done - список завершившихся тасков
        # pending - список незавершившихся тасков

        # Циклом идем по списку завершившихся тасков, проверяем результат
        for item in done:
            result = item.result()
            if result is not None:
                # Останавливаем незавершившиеся таски
                for pending_task in pending:
                    pending_task.cancel()
                
                return result

        # Если среди выполненных не было результатов не None, то идем на второй круг
        # Список незавершившихся тасков становится списком тасков, из которых мы будем ожидать результата
        futures = pending


async def check_site():
    site = ['https://yandex.ru/internet', 'https://wtfismyip.com', 'https://whoer.net', 'https://2ip.ru']

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        futures = []
        for link in site:
            futures.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(link, session)))

        result = await wait_first_completed_not_none(futures)
        if result is None:
            print(result)
        else:
            print(result[:1000])



def main():
    asyncio.run(check_site())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Пример результата:

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="ru"><head><title data-react-helmet="true">Яндекс.Интернетометр — проверка скорости интернета</title><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="description" content="Тест скорости интернета. IP-адрес, операционная система, версия браузера, cookies, разрешение экрана и другие параметры системы."/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="keywords" content="скорость, интернет, тест, измерить, интернетометр, проверить, интернет соединение, узнать, замерить, cookies, cookie, версия браузера, разрешение экрана"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="og:type" content="website"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="og:title" content="Яндекс.Интернетометр — ваша скорость интернета"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="og:description" content="Проверка скорости интернета. IP-адрес, операционная система, версия браузера, cookies, разрешение экрана и другие параметры системы."/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="og:url" content="https://yandex.ru/internet/"/><meta data-react-helm
```

В зависимости от того, какой сайт ответит раньше, результат может быть другим.

Comment: решение очень интересное, но мне нужно было указать что мы делаем сurl запросы, почитав документацию я не нашел у aiohttp.ClientSession()  работу с curl

Comment: @АлександрЧерных curl - это HTTP клиент, через него можно отправлять HTTP запросы. aiohttp - тоже сам по себе HTTP клиент (ну и сервер тоже, но в данном случае нас клиентская сторона интересует), через него тоже можно отправлять HTTP запросы (очевидно). Для отправки HTTP запросов не обязательно использовать именно curl, это только один из множества HTTP клиентов.

Comment: Кроме того, функция wait_first_completed_not_none в ответе более-менее универсальна, не привязана именно к aiohttp, по идее в него точно так же можно передать ваши futures, которые в отдельных потоках.

Comment: огромное спасибо разобрался.  async def wait_first_completed_not_none(futures) - этой функции действительно было достаточно.

Comment: в итоге думал что разобрался но все равно не так работает.  Таски выполняются по очереди и берется первый таск который выполнился (прерывания тоже нет - ждет когда все таски выполнятся.) код выложил выше.

Comment: @АлександрЧерных нужно смотреть что у вас в функции check_dns_no_class, я предполагаю, что в ней какой-то блокирующий (не умеющий работать асинхронно) код.

Comment: Вопрос решился. проблема была с сабпроцесом. Но теперь там возникла другая проблема.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518521/runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-pipe